# How to print entire ELF file header with all its information?

Tags: c, linux, binaryfiles, elf

I have to print the ELF file header. All the data it contains, just like when running readelf -h hello.bin. The program is in C. This is what i have untill now:

```
  typedef struct elf64_hdr {
  unsigned char e_ident[EI_NIDENT]; /* ELF "magic number" */
  Elf64_Half e_type;
  Elf64_Half e_machine;
  Elf64_Word e_version;
  Elf64_Addr e_entry;       /* Entry point virtual address */
  Elf64_Off e_phoff;        /* Program header table file offset */
  Elf64_Off e_shoff;        /* Section header table file offset */
  Elf64_Word e_flags;
  Elf64_Half e_ehsize;
  Elf64_Half e_phentsize;
  Elf64_Half e_phnum;
  Elf64_Half e_shentsize;
  Elf64_Half e_shnum;
  Elf64_Half e_shstrndx;
} Elf64_Ehdr;

typedef struct elf64_shdr {
  Elf64_Word sh_name;       /* Section name, index in string tbl */
  Elf64_Word sh_type;       /* Type of section */
  Elf64_Xword sh_flags;     /* Miscellaneous section attributes */
  Elf64_Addr sh_addr;       /* Section virtual addr at execution */
  Elf64_Off sh_offset;      /* Section file offset */
  Elf64_Xword sh_size;      /* Size of section in bytes */
  Elf64_Word sh_link;       /* Index of another section */
  Elf64_Word sh_info;       /* Additional section information */
  Elf64_Xword sh_addralign; /* Section alignment */
  Elf64_Xword sh_entsize;   /* Entry size if section holds table */
} Elf64_Shdr;
```

These are the structures.
Here are the variables declared in main:

```
  FILE* ElfFile = NULL;
  char* SectNames = NULL;
  Elf64_Ehdr elfHdr;
  Elf64_Shdr sectHdr;
  uint32_t idx;
```

Here is the relevant part of the code for printing, that needs your help:

```
// read ELF header, first thing in the file
  fread(&elfHdr, 1, sizeof(Elf64_Ehdr), ElfFile); 
  SectNames = malloc(sectHdr.sh_size); //variable for section names (like "Magic", "Data" etc.)
  fseek(ElfFile, sectHdr.sh_offset, SEEK_SET); //going to the offset of the section
  fread(SectNames, 1, sectHdr.sh_size, ElfFile); //reading the size of section
  for(int i=0; i<sectHdr.sh_size; i++)
  {
    char *name1 = "";
    fseek(ElfFile, elfHdr.e_shoff + i*sizeof(sectHdr), SEEK_SET);
    fread(&sectHdr, 1, sizeof(sectHdr), ElfFile);
    name1 = SectNames + sectHdr.sh_name;
    printf("%s \n", name1);
  }
```

The code compiles but does not print anything. I expected to print the strings like "Magic", "Data", "Class" etc...

Comment: `SectNames = malloc(sectHdr.sh_size);` The code to read `sectHdr` has not executed at that point. If that isn't the issue then please provide complete code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: While you certainly roll your own version, there is an ELF library that can do much of what you want to do already: `libelf`. You can install the development package for this from your distro. (e.g.) In fedora, it is `elfutils-libelf-devel`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `+` operator to add strings in C.

This line:

```
char *name1 = "";
```

Means `name1` points to an empty constant string.
It does not allocate memory for some string object you can add strings to.

So this code:

```
name1 = SectNames + sectHdr.sh_name;
```

Just puts a garbage value (some number) in `name1` which will result in undefined behavior (your program can crash, or print nothing, or print random characters).

To print section name, you would need code like this:

```
printf("Section name: %u\n", sectHdr.sh_name);
```

This will format the value in `sectHdr.sh_name` to text and output it to the screen.

You will have to do a similar thing with all other fields, one by one, but you must pay attention to the field type and use the correct format specifier.

`%u` means "unsigned integer" which is the closest thing to `Elf64_Word` that `printf` has.
Check carefully for other types and [suitable specifiers](https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet/)!

Comment: I modified this but still no warns nor printing..

Comment: @AnewHope you don't check the results of your `fread` operations or what value you got in `sectHdr.sh_size`. It is possible your code fails in some other place and never enters the loop. You should start by printing `sectHdr.sh_size` for debug and also check return value of each `fread` to see if it actually reads the amount of bytes you expected!

Comment: @AnewHope also, make sure to compile with -Wall -pedantic and -std=gnu99 (I think this is the standard you need for working with Linux includes) if you want to see proper warnings.